# How to exclude a click handler from an element and its descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I exclude my `#lightbox` from a handler, attached to the body?

```
$('body :not(#lightbox)').click(function() {    
    $('#lightbox').hide();
});
```

The Lighbox is centered. When the user clicks right or left from the box, it should be closed. This should not happen when the `#lightbox`or any descendant of it are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to stop event propagation of click from `lightbox` element, but it may not be the safe option as it can break other global handlers.

Another is to see whether the event target is inside the `lightbox` element

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#lightbox').length) {
        $('#lightbox').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: @DavidFreimaucher your selector will select all elements other than the `#lightbox` element which includes the descendant elements of `lightbox` also and will add the click handler to each of those elements... so when you click on  a descendant of `lightbox` the handler will get executed

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Is there no possibility like  in CSS to filter those elements with the selektor like `$('body :not(#lightbox > *)` or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to remove handler from your lightbox by placing following script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body :not(#lightbox)').unbind('click');
});
```

But note that after this script your click event handler never fired.
Also you are able return false inside your function which will not process your further script for that function.